# Emacs daemon: swapping keys

Tags: emacs, elisp, dvorak, emacsclient, eshell

I'd like to swap C-x and C-u with Emacs daemon (since I switched to Dvorak layout). The regular  `keyboard-translate` doesn't work with Emacs daemon. In the help-gnu-emacs I found a solution: I should use `(define-key key-translation-map ...)` instead of `(keyboard-translate ...)`. However, even though the swap works without problems in many cases (e.g., C-x s) I've been finding cases in which the swap doesn't work properly such as in C-u M-x eshell (when I type this last command all I get is "eeee". But if I type M-x twice the command works as it's supposed to). Do you know any solution to this problem?

Further details:

That's what I have in my .emacs:

```
;; swap C-x and C-u
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-x] [?\C-u])
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-u] [?\C-x])
```

I'm using Emacs 23.3.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're seeing an existing Emacs [bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2011-09/msg00023.html).  I'm not sure about the priority of this bug, but if you send your user story to the bug tracker e-mail: `9417@debbugs.gnu.org`, it'll get more visibility and possibly get fixed.